# Why are Sobolev spaces $W^{m,p}$ denoted with the letter "W"?

Tags: notation, sobolev-spaces

Why are the [Sobolev spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space) $W^{m,p}$ where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $1\le p\le \infty$ denoted with the letter "$W$"?

I know they are denoted with the letter $H$ when $p=2$ because, in this case, they are Hilbert spaces. However, I don't get the "$W$".

EDIT: does this have a link with the fact their definition involves the so-called "weak derivatives"?

Comment: $m \in \mathbb{N}$ or $m \in [0;\infty[$, and $p \ge 1$ is the $p$ from $L^p$ spaces, which are Hilbert spaces only if $p=2$ (otherwise they are Banach spaces)

Comment: Probably from "weak". See [History of Sobolev space notations](http://mathoverflow.net/q/90527).

Comment: @404 Thanks for the link. I didn't find it yesterday.